# install lua 5.4 binaries and libraries step by step on Windows

Tags: lua, iup

I don't know how to install this for this little chunck of code to work, thanks in advance:

The code works in LuaForWindows 5.1, because all libraries are included. But not in 5.4 as I don't know how to install libraries: Latest LuaForWindows is up to 5.1 only...

```
require( "iuplua" )
ml = iup.multiline
    {
    expand="YES",
    value="Quit this multiline edit app to continue Tutorial!",
    border="YES"
    }
dlg = iup.dialog{ml; title="IupMultiline", size="QUARTERxQUARTER",}
dlg:show()
print("Exit GUI app to continue!")
iup.MainLoop()
```

Comment: So, your question is "how to build iuplua"?

Comment: My question is in the title's message... How to install lua+ required libraries for the piece of code to work on latest lua version. Afaik, I don't need to build lua 'cos there are precompiled binaries AND libraries, but I don't know how to install them, e.g. the iuplua...

Comment: Just install Lua and Luarocks, then use the latter to install the library

Comment: also, `iuplua` is apparently not available through luarocks, but you can easily download it directly from sourceforge

Comment: If iuplua is not available from luarocks I should manually copy the contents to some folders, but I don't know where exactly. Can you please give some specific example ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

To make just that Lua code to work with Lua 5.4 you can use the IUP tools pre-compiled binaries which include Lua and all necessary files.